# how to pass 2d array from javascript to java spring controller

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, spring-mvc

So I have the following sample 
table and I need to pass the values of each cell per row to my controller.

[sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmEiU.png)

Now once I click on the TEST button, each cell values will be placed inside an array. The result would be something like this :

```
[
  [
    {"key":"A","value":"1"},
    {"key":"B","value":"2"},
    {"key":"C","value":"3"},
    {"key":"D","value":"4"},
    {"key":"E","value":"5"},
  ],
  [
    {"key":"A","value":"6"},
    {"key":"B","value":"7"},
    {"key":"C","value":"8"},
    {"key":"D","value":"9"},
    {"key":"E","value":"0"},
  ]
]
```

How will I pass this kind of array to my spring controller?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There are many ways... An example would be: JaxRS with REST. Then you can pass the JSON to Java and intercept it there.

Comment: So you either post a form to the server with the data or you make an Ajax request